# What is the analogue command in Ivy to show output in console like mvn dependency:tree in maven?

Tags: maven-2, ivy

The following maven command shows the dependency tree on console if run in the project directory where pom.xml is present.

mvn dependency:tree

What is the command which does the same in Ivy?

Answer (score 0):

That would be [dependencytree](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/use/dependencytree.html) ant task, it "ASCII draws" a dependency tree in the console. It's simple - there's no parameters/xml attributes or child nodes, just write `<dependencytree />`

Comment: I don't want to change anything in build.xml or ivy.xml

Comment: How are you invoking ivy?